# Two questions about typesetting a Roman missal

Tags: horizontal-alignment, multicol, columnbreak

I'm putting together a Roman missal for use by the laity at Traditional Latin Mass. Thus far, I've faced two main problems, which are apparent in my MWE.

```
\documentclass[a6paper,pagesize,12pt]{book}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{color}

\usepackage[layout=a5paper,vmargin=0.4in,tmargin=0.6in,hmargin=0.4in,paperheight=216mm,paperwidth=154mm,showframe=false]{geometry}

\usepackage{multicol}

\pagenumbering{gobble}

\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\newcommand\kom[1]{{\vspace{0.2cm}\begin{center}\footnotesize \color{red} #1 \end{center}}}
\newcommand{\+}{{\maltese}}

\sloppy

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
{\LARGE \textbf{\textsc{Red svete maše}}} \\ \vspace{1cm}
\textbf{Pristopne molitve (KLEČIMO)} \\
\kom{Mašnik pripravi kelih, odpre knjigo, nato gre pred stopnice, se pokriža in moli. Z njim se pokrižam, pokleknem in molim (po tiho):}
\end{center}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\setlength\columnseprule{0.4pt}

Mašnik: In nomine \+ Patris, et Filii et Spiritus Sancti. Amen.

Mašnik: (Ant.) Introibo ad altare Dei.

\textbf{Strežnik: Ad Deum qui lætíficat iuventútem meam.}

M. Iúdica me, Deus, et discérne cáusam meam de gente non sancta: ab hómine iníquo et dolóso érue me.

\textbf{S. Quia tu es, Deus, fortitúdo mea: quare me repulísti, et quare tristis incédo, dum afflígit me inimícus?}

M. Emítte lucem tuam et veritátem tuam: ipsa me deduxérunt et adduxérunt in montem sanctum tuum, et in tabernácula tua.

\textbf{S. Et introíbo ad altáre Dei: ad Deum qui lætíficat iuventútem meam.}

M. Confitébor tibi in cíthara, Deus, Deus meus: quare tristis es anima mea, et quare contúrbas me?

\textbf{S. Spera in Deo, quóniam adhuc confitébor illi: salutáre vultus mei, et Deus meus.}

\columnbreak

V imenu \+ Očeta in Sina in Svetega Duha. Amen. \\

Stopil bom k Božjemu oltarju.

K Bogu, ki razveseljuje mojo mladost.

Sodi me, Bog, in razsodi mojo pravdo zoper nezvesto ljudstvo; krivičnega in zvijačnega človeka me reši.

Ker si ti moja moč, o Bog, zakaj si me zavrgel? In zakaj hodim žalosten, ko me stiska sovražnik?

Pošlji svojo luč in svojo resnico, da me popeljeta na tvojo sveto goro in v tvoje šotore.

In stopil bom k Božjemu oltarju; k Bogu, ki razveseljuje mojo mladost.

Hvalil te bom s citrami, Bog, moj Bog! Zakaj si žalostna, moja duša, in zakaj me vznemirjaš?

\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The original Latin text is on the left side, and the translation (into Slovene, my mother language) is supposed to be aligned to it on the right side. I tried to achieve this with `\columnbreak` in `multicols`. The problem is that this only works for one page. This brings me to my first question.

**1. How can I make `\columnbreak` work across pages?**

The second problem is that I don't know how to align text in these columns, so that the beginning of the original Latin paragraph would align with the translation (this will undoubtedly reduce users' confusion when trying to follow the ritual of the mass). So, my second question is:

**2. How can I align text in two columns side-by-side?**

If you know of any better solution to my problems, you are also welcome to suggest them (`minipage`, as I've read, could be a good alternative). Thank you for your answers in advance and God bless and keep you always.

**EDIT**

I am now using the `paracol` package. If you know how to align parallel paragraphs (by their beginning), please tell me. The answer which will achieve this goal will be marked with a tick, as the package has resolved all of my other problems. Much thanks to @DavidPurton, who suggested it, and God bless!

Comment: I think the `paracol` package is better suited for this application.

Comment: @DavidPurton Thank you, I'll have a look at it. God bless and keep you always.

Comment: Also, a [longtable](https://ctan.org/pkg/longtable) with two columns may work OK. One paragraph in each cell, latin to the left, Slovene to the right. The pagebreak will be between two rows.

Comment: @Sveinung Thanks for the suggestion and God bless!

Comment: @DavidPurton Seems to be a bug. I manage to get it to work with alternative text.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As requested, here’s a solution with [`paracol`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/paracol), a newer and more flexible package for parallel columns that is still being updated.  This is closer to what you wanted, and will work better than my original answer if you want the columns to have different widths or spacing.

As you can see, I defined some macros for convenience.  It uses Unicode and modern fonts, and should be compiled in LuaLaTeX, but it would not be difficult to adapt to PDFTeX if you really wanted to.

I also added a couple of packages: `babel` to support multilingual text (such as hyphenation patterns and font switching if necessary) and `microtype` to support font expansion, which should reduce the need for sloppiness.

```
\documentclass[a6paper,pagesize,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[layout=a5paper, vmargin=0.4in, tmargin=0.6in, hmargin=0.4in,
            paperheight=216mm, paperwidth=154mm, showframe=false
           ]{geometry}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[latin, main=slovene]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec, microtype, parskip, paracol}

\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchUppercase}
\babelfont{rm}
          [Scale=1.0,
           Language=Default,
           Ligatures={Common, TeX}
          ]{TeX Gyre Schola} % Or your font of choice.

\newfontfamily\symbolfont{DejaVu Sans}

\pagenumbering{gobble}
\setlength\columnseprule{0.4pt}
\sloppy

\newcommand\kom[1]{{\vspace{0.2cm}\begin{center}\footnotesize \color{red} #1 \end{center}}}
\newcommand{\+}{{\symbolfont\symbol{"2720}}} % Maltese cross.

\newcommand\Masnik{\foreignlanguage{slovene}{Mašnik}}
\newcommand\Streznik{\foreignlanguage{slovene}{Strežnik}}

\newcommand\chunks[2]{%
\begin{leftcolumn*}\begin{otherlanguage}{latin}%
{#1}%
\end{otherlanguage}\end{leftcolumn*}%
\begin{rightcolumn}\begin{otherlanguage}{slovene}%
{#2}%
\end{otherlanguage}\end{rightcolumn}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
{\LARGE \textbf{\textsc{Red svete maše}}} \\ \vspace{1cm}
\textbf{Pristopne molitve (KLEČIMO)} \\
\kom{Mašnik pripravi kelih, odpre knjigo, nato gre pred stopnice, se pokriža in moli. Z njim se pokrižam, pokleknem in molim (po tiho):}
\end{center}

\begin{paracol}{2}
  \chunks{\Masnik: In nomine \+ Patris, et Filii et Spiritus Sancti. Amen.}
         {V imenu \+ Očeta in Sina in Svetega Duha. Amen.}
  \chunks{\Masnik: (Ant.) Introibo ad altare Dei.}
         {Stopil bom k Božjemu oltarju.}
  \chunks{\textbf{\Streznik: Ad Deum qui lætíficat iuventútem meam.}}
         {\textbf{K Bogu, ki razveseljuje mojo mladost.}}
  \chunks{M. Iúdica me, Deus, et discérne cáusam meam de gente non sancta: ab hómine iníquo et dolóso érue me.}
         {Sodi me, Bog, in razsodi mojo pravdo zoper nezvesto ljudstvo; krivičnega in zvijačnega človeka me reši.}
  \chunks{\textbf{S. Quia tu es, Deus, fortitúdo mea: quare me repulísti, et quare tristis incédo, dum afflígit me inimícus?}}
         {\textbf{Ker si ti moja moč, o Bog, zakaj si me zavrgel? In zakaj hodim žalosten, ko me stiska sovražnik?}}
  \chunks{M. Emítte lucem tuam et veritátem tuam: ipsa me deduxérunt et adduxérunt in montem sanctum tuum, et in tabernácula tua.}
         {Pošlji svojo luč in svojo resnico, da me popeljeta na tvojo sveto goro in v tvoje šotore.}
  \chunks{\textbf{S. Et introíbo ad altáre Dei: ad Deum qui lætíficat iuventútem meam.}}
         {\textbf{In stopil bom k Božjemu oltarju; k Bogu, ki razveseljuje mojo mladost.}}
  \chunks{M. Confitébor tibi in cíthara, Deus, Deus meus: quare tristis es anima mea, et quare contúrbas me?}
         {Hvalil te bom s citrami, Bog, moj Bog! Zakaj si žalostna, moja duša, in zakaj me vznemirjaš?}
\end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

[image: Missal sample]

### Previous Answer

Here is a version that uses the `pdfcolparcolumns` update to `parcolumns`.  It should at least work with color.

```
\documentclass[a6paper,pagesize,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[latin, main=slovene]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[layout=a5paper, vmargin=0.4in, tmargin=0.6in, hmargin=0.4in,
            paperheight=216mm, paperwidth=154mm, showframe=false
           ]{geometry}

\usepackage{pdfcolparcolumns}
\usepackage{parskip}

\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchUppercase}
\babelfont{rm}
          [Scale=1.0,
           Language=Default,
           Ligatures={Common, TeX}
          ]{TeX Gyre Schola} % Or your font of choice.

\newfontfamily\symbolfont{DejaVu Sans}

\pagenumbering{gobble}

\newcommand\kom[1]{{\vspace{0.2cm}\begin{center}\footnotesize \color{red} #1 \end{center}}}
\newcommand{\+}{{\symbolfont\symbol{"2720}}} % Maltese cross.

\newcommand\Masnik{\foreignlanguage{slovene}{Mašnik}}
\newcommand\Streznik{\foreignlanguage{slovene}{Strežnik}}

\newcommand\chunks[2]{%
\colchunk[1]{\begin{otherlanguage}{latin}\par{#1}\end{otherlanguage}}%
\colchunk[2]{\begin{otherlanguage}{slovene}\par{#2}\end{otherlanguage}}%
\colplacechunks%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
{\LARGE \textbf{\textsc{Red svete maše}}} \\ \vspace{1cm}
\textbf{Pristopne molitve (KLEČIMO)} \\
\kom{Mašnik pripravi kelih, odpre knjigo, nato gre pred stopnice, se pokriža in moli. Z njim se pokrižam, pokleknem in molim (po tiho):}
\end{center}

\begin{parcolumns}[distance=1em, nofirstindent, rulebetween, sloppy]{2}

  \chunks{\Masnik: In nomine \+ Patris, et Filii et Spiritus Sancti. Amen.}
         {V imenu \+ Očeta in Sina in Svetega Duha. Amen.}

  \chunks{\Masnik: (Ant.) Introibo ad altare Dei.}
         {Stopil bom k Božjemu oltarju.}

  \chunks{\textbf{\Streznik: Ad Deum qui lætíficat iuventútem meam.}}
         {\textbf{K Bogu, ki razveseljuje mojo mladost.}}

  \chunks{M. Iúdica me, Deus, et discérne cáusam meam de gente non sancta: ab hómine iníquo et dolóso érue me.}
         {Sodi me, Bog, in razsodi mojo pravdo zoper nezvesto ljudstvo; krivičnega in zvijačnega človeka me reši.}

  \chunks{\textbf{S. Quia tu es, Deus, fortitúdo mea: quare me repulísti, et quare tristis incédo, dum afflígit me inimícus?}}
         {\textbf{Ker si ti moja moč, o Bog, zakaj si me zavrgel? In zakaj hodim žalosten, ko me stiska sovražnik?}}

  \chunks{M. Emítte lucem tuam et veritátem tuam: ipsa me deduxérunt et adduxérunt in montem sanctum tuum, et in tabernácula tua.}
         {Pošlji svojo luč in svojo resnico, da me popeljeta na tvojo sveto goro in v tvoje šotore.}

  \chunks{\textbf{S. Et introíbo ad altáre Dei: ad Deum qui lætíficat iuventútem meam.}}
         {\textbf{In stopil bom k Božjemu oltarju; k Bogu, ki razveseljuje mojo mladost.}}

  \chunks{M. Confitébor tibi in cíthara, Deus, Deus meus: quare tristis es anima mea, et quare contúrbas me?}
         {Hvalil te bom s citrami, Bog, moj Bog! Zakaj si žalostna, moja duša, in zakaj me vznemirjaš?}

\end{parcolumns}
\end{document}
```

[image: Missal sample]

I simply copied the text from your MWE, and do not speak Slovene, so I apologize for any errors.

**Edit:** Thanks to Sveinung for pointing out an error with the spacing.  It explicitly starts a new paragraph with every chunk now.  To change the paragraph spacing, `\usepackage[skip=\someLength]{parskip}`.

Comment: Very cool, I'll be using this from now on! Lord God, Jesus Christ, bless and keep you always. JMJ +++

Comment: My best wishes for your score 10k :-)

Comment: @Sveinung Thanks for pointing this out. I added `\par` commands so that each chunk now uses paragraph spacing.

Comment: @GregorPerčič Changed to use `paracol` like you wanted. You were right: it’s a more flexible package that’s still being maintained.

Answer (score 7):

I have updated the [longtable](https://ctan.org/pkg/longtable) solution, using the class [scrartcl](https://ctan.org/pkg/scrartcl) from  the [KOMA-script bundle](https://ctan.org/pkg/koma-scrpt). I have also added new font, Palantino, a very nice and readable font.

Title is set using [KOMA-script](https://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) features. Necessary [babel](https://ctan.org/pkg/babel) environments are piped into the column.

You have now a better [paracol](https://ctan.org/pkg/paracol)-solution than before, but I am still of the opinion that [longtable](https://ctan.org/pkg/longtable) is a better and safer environment for typesetting parallel column, unless you have very long paragraphs which may be a challenge for good page breaks.

Working [paracol](https://ctan.org/pkg/paracol) MWE is at the end of the answer:

**longtable**

[image]

```
\documentclass[table, latin, slovene, fontsize=12pt, parskip=full,titlepage=false]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tgpagella}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amssymb, array, longtable}
\usepackage{xcolor, babel}
\usepackage[babel=true]{microtype}

\usepackage[layout=a5paper,vmargin=0.4in, tmargin=0.6in,%
                      hmargin=0.4in,paperheight=216mm,%
                      includehead, footskip=1.5\baselineskip,%
                      paperwidth=154mm]{geometry}


\newcommand{\+}{{\maltese}}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\begin{otherlanguage}{latin}}p{\dimexpr(0.5\linewidth-\tabcolsep-0.5\arrayrulewidth)}<{\end{otherlanguage}\vspace{0.5\baselineskip}}}
\newcolumntype{S}{>{\begin{otherlanguage}{slovene}}p{\dimexpr(0.5\linewidth-\tabcolsep-0.5\arrayrulewidth)}<{\end{otherlanguage}\vspace{0.5\baselineskip}}}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{1em}
\arrayrulecolor{gray}
\renewcommand*\titlepagestyle{empty}
\renewcommand\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\setkomafont{subject}{\LARGE\bfseries}
\setkomafont{title}{\large\mdseries}
\setkomafont{subtitle}{\color{red}\footnotesize}

\begin{document}

\subject{Red svete maše}
\title{\large Pristopne molitve (KLEČIMO)}
\subtitle{Mašnik pripravi kelih, odpre knjigo, nato gre pred stopnice, se pokriža in moli. \mbox{Z njim} se pokrižam, pokleknem in molim (po tiho): }
\date{\vspace{-4\baselineskip}}

\maketitle

\begin{longtable}[c]{@{}L|S@{}}
Mašnik: In nomine \+ Patris, et  Fílii, et Spíritus Sancti. Amen. &
V imenu \+ Očeta in Sina in Svetega Duha. Amen.\\

Mašnik: (Ant.) Introíbo ad altáre Dei. &
Stopil bom k Božjemu oltarju.\\

\bfseries Strežnik: Ad Deum qui lætíficat iuventútem meam. &
K Bogu, ki razveseljuje mojo mladost.\\

M. Iúdica me, Deus, et discérne cáusam meam de gente non sancta: ab hómine iníquo et dolóso érue me.&
Sodi me, Bog, in razsodi mojo pravdo zoper nezvesto ljudstvo; krivičnega in zvijačnega človeka me reši.\\

\bfseries S. Quia tu es, Deus, fortitúdo mea: quare me repulísti, et quare tristis incédo, dum afflígit me inimícus?&
Ker si ti moja moč, o Bog, zakaj si me zavrgel? In zakaj hodim žalosten, ko me stiska sovražnik? \\

M. Emítte lucem tuam et veritátem tuam: ipsa me deduxérunt et adduxérunt in montem sanctum tuum, et in tabernácula tua.&
Pošlji svojo luč in svojo resnico, da me popeljeta na tvojo sveto goro in v tvoje šotore.\\

\bfseries S. Et introíbo ad altáre Dei: ad Deum qui lætíficat iuventútem meam. &
In stopil bom k Božjemu oltarju; k Bogu, ki razveseljuje mojo mladost.\\

M. Confitébor tibi in cíthara, Deus, Deus meus: quare tristis es anima mea, et quare contúrbas me? &
Hvalil te bom s citrami, Bog, moj Bog! Zakaj si žalostna, moja duša, in zakaj me vznemirjaš?\\

\bfseries S. Spera in Deo, quóniam adhuc confitébor illi: salutáre vultus mei, et Deus meus.&
Upaj v Boga, zakaj še ga bom hvalil; on je pomoč mojega obličja in moj Bog.\\\end{longtable}
```

\end{document}**paracol**

```
\documentclass[a6paper,pagesize,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amssymb, array, paracol}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[latin,slovene]{babel}        % Thanks to David Purton
\usepackage[babel=true]{microtype}       % Important for nice typesetting

\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameLinethickness{.4pt}

\usepackage[layout=a5paper,vmargin=0.4in,tmargin=0.6in,hmargin=0.4in,paperheight=216mm,paperwidth=154mm,showframe=false]{geometry}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\newcommand\kom[1]{{\vspace{0.2cm}\begin{center}\footnotesize \color{red} #1 \end{center}}}
\newcommand{\+}{{\maltese}}

\newcolumntype{N}{p{\dimexpr(0.5\linewidth-\tabcolsep-0.5\arrayrulewidth)}}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
{\LARGE \textbf{\textsc{Red svete maše}}} \\ \vspace{1cm}
\textbf{Pristopne molitve (KLEČIMO)} \\
\kom{Mašnik pripravi kelih, odpre knjigo, nato gre pred stopnice, se pokriža in moli. Z njim se pokrižam, pokleknem in molim (po tiho):}
\end{center}


    \begin{paracol}{2}
      \switchcolumn[1]* Text in language 1, which is much longer than you thin
      \switchcolumn[0]  Text in language 1, which is much longer than you thin
     \switchcolumn[1]* Text in language 1
      \switchcolumn[0]  Text in language 2
     \switchcolumn[1]* Text in language 1
      \switchcolumn[0]  Text in language 2

    \end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you and God bless and keep you always! I've found an answer with `paracol`, but I think it would be disrespectful to not give you a tick after the work you've put into your answer. See you around... Pax. +++

Comment: @GregorPerčič, you might get better results with using `\usepackage[latin,slovene]{babel}`. It will hyphenate better in the two languages and you don't have to use `\sloppy` globally, just for some paragraphs.

Comment: @GregorPerčič And use [microtype](https://ctan.org/pkg/microtype) and a supported font (f. ex. [latin modern](https://ctan.org/pkg/lmodern) to get an even nicer typesetting. With [microtype](https://ctan.org/pkg/microtype), you never need to use `\sloppy`.

Answer (score 6):

I've found a solution using `paracol`. The basic idea is to synchronize columns with switching from `leftcolumn*` to `rightcolumn`. This code puts every next left paragraph at the bottom of every previous right paragraph.

```
\documentclass[a6paper,pagesize,12pt]{book}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{color}

\usepackage[layout=a5paper,vmargin=0.4in,tmargin=0.6in,hmargin=0.4in,paperheight=216mm,paperwidth=154mm,showframe=false]{geometry}

\usepackage{paracol}

\pagenumbering{gobble}

\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\newcommand\kom[1]{{\vspace{0.2cm}\begin{center}\footnotesize \color{red} #1 \end{center} \vspace{0.2cm}}}
\newcommand{\+}{{\maltese}}

\sloppy

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
{\LARGE \textbf{\textsc{Red svete maše}}} \\ \vspace{0.8cm}
\textbf{Pristopne molitve (KLEČIMO)} \\
\kom{Mašnik pripravi kelih, odpre knjigo, nato gre pred stopnice, se pokriža in moli. Z njim se pokrižam, pokleknem in molim (po tiho):}
\end{center}

\begin{paracol}{2}

\setlength\columnseprule{0.4pt}

\begin{leftcolumn*}
Mašnik: In nomine \+ Patris, et  Fílii, et Spíritus Sancti. Amen.
\end{leftcolumn*}

\begin{rightcolumn}
V imenu \+ Očeta in Sina in Svetega Duha. Amen.
\end{rightcolumn}

\begin{leftcolumn*}
Mašnik: (Ant.) Introíbo ad altáre Dei.
\end{leftcolumn*}

\begin{rightcolumn}
Stopil bom k Božjemu oltarju.
\end{rightcolumn}

\begin{leftcolumn*}
\textbf{Strežnik: Ad Deum qui lætíficat iuventútem meam.}
\end{leftcolumn*}

\begin{rightcolumn}
K Bogu, ki razveseljuje mojo mladost.
\end{rightcolumn}

\begin{leftcolumn*}
M. Iúdica me, Deus, et discérne cáusam meam de gente non sancta: ab hómine iníquo et dolóso érue me.
\end{leftcolumn*}

\begin{rightcolumn}
Sodi me, Bog, in razsodi mojo pravdo zoper nezvesto ljudstvo; krivičnega in zvijačnega človeka me reši.
\end{rightcolumn}

\begin{leftcolumn*}
\textbf{S. Quia tu es, Deus, fortitúdo mea: quare me repulísti, et quare tristis incédo, dum afflígit me inimícus?}
\end{leftcolumn*}

\begin{rightcolumn}
Ker si ti moja moč, o Bog, zakaj si me zavrgel? In zakaj hodim žalosten, ko me stiska sovražnik?
\end{rightcolumn}

\begin{leftcolumn*}
M. Emítte lucem tuam et veritátem tuam: ipsa me deduxérunt et adduxérunt in montem sanctum tuum, et in tabernácula tua.
\end{leftcolumn*}

\begin{rightcolumn}
Pošlji svojo luč in svojo resnico, da me popeljeta na tvojo sveto goro in v tvoje šotore.
\end{rightcolumn}

\begin{leftcolumn*}
\textbf{S. Et introíbo ad altáre Dei: ad Deum qui lætíficat iuventútem meam.}
\end{leftcolumn*}

\begin{rightcolumn}
In stopil bom k Božjemu oltarju; k Bogu, ki razveseljuje mojo mladost.
\end{rightcolumn}

\begin{leftcolumn*}
M. Confitébor tibi in cíthara, Deus, Deus meus: quare tristis es anima mea, et quare contúrbas me?
\end{leftcolumn*}

\begin{rightcolumn}
Hvalil te bom s citrami, Bog, moj Bog! Zakaj si žalostna, moja duša, in zakaj me vznemirjaš?
\end{rightcolumn}

\begin{leftcolumn*}
\textbf{S. Spera in Deo, quóniam adhuc confitébor illi: salutáre vultus mei, et Deus meus.}
\end{leftcolumn*}

\begin{rightcolumn}
Upaj v Boga, zakaj še ga bom hvalil; on je pomoč mojega obličja in moj Bog.
\end{rightcolumn}

\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

The first page of the output looks like this.

[image]

Comment: You may accept your own answer.

Comment: Very nice.  You may want to look at the `liturg` and `ecclesiastic` packages too as you refine your document.

Comment: @Sveinung Nah, you deserve it. :) Pax. +++

Comment: @Thérèse I've had a look at the `liturg` package, but sadly, it is of no use to me, since my task is to typeset a bilingual missal. Will check `ecclesiastic` out, though. Thank you for your suggestions and God bless and keep you always! Pax. JMJ +++