# Automatically apply different fonts to different languages

Tags: fonts, babel, languages

I'm working on an Esperanto tutorial in Simplified Chinese. Using `\babelfont` I appointed Noto Serif as Chinese font and Cambria for Esperanto. However, using `\selectlanguage` or `\foreignlanguage` each time I need to switch language seems too convoluted. Is it possible that I can make it **automatic** to change the font when encounter Esperanto characters (or all Latin characters)? Compiler XeLatex.
P.S. I don't want to use `xeCJK` or such CJK-supporting packages, for they provide too few Chinese fonts.

Comment: Possibly? [Is it possible to typeset Unicode input in multiple language scripts automatically without inserting special commands?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/449764)

Comment: Yes, so long as that is the only language that uses the Latin script.

Comment: If you use Esperanto and another language in a regular pattern, such as parallel columns, [you can automate the language switch inside that](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/505534/two-questions-about-typesetting-a-roman-missal).