# How do I make columns à la Canadian Law?

Tags: languages, columns

Right now I'm trying to typeset the Dao De Jing in two columns where English is on one side and Classical Chinese is on the other. I want to make it so that it'll flow independently into the next page regardless of the content on any previous one. (I know that that isn't normally the way it would go but for my own reasons I do need it this way.) So ideally it would look something like this:

```
The Way that can be followed is           道可道，非常道。名可名，非常名。
not the eternal Way. The name             無名天地之始有名萬物之母。故常無
that can be named is not the              欲以觀其妙、常有欲以觀其徵。此两
                    %%%%%%%%%%%pagebreak%%%%%%%%
eternal name. The nameless is the         者同出而異名。同謂之玄。玄之又  
origin of heaven and earth. While         玄、衆妙之門。
naming is the origin of the
myriad things. Therefore, always
desireless, you see the mystery.
Ever desiring, you see the
manifestations. These two are the
same— When they appear they are
named differently.
```

Canadian laws do the same thing with English on the left and French on the right. Although I've seen some solutions, none of the ones that I've tried have worked for me. Any help would be greatly appreciated. (And if you don't mind just so that I can be able to customize it further an explanation of *why* your solution works would be great, but if it's too much dw about it.) Thanks!

Comment: How about `parallel.sty`.

Comment: Please look at https://ctan.org/pkg/paracol or https://ctan.org/pkg/ledmac.

Comment: Here [are a couple of versions I did of something similar.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/505534/two-questions-about-typesetting-a-roman-missal) One difference is that it makes every paragraph line up in both languages, but you can usually adjust the width of the columns so that there are no large gaps.

Comment: @Davislor Ooo that's awesome!! I'll probably wind up using that too at some point where the lining up actually matters. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out package `paracol` to see if that meets your needs.

Comment: Thanks! That worked perfectly :)